# Python | The .Bat File Closes After Opening

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduler, tweepy

I have a .BAT file.  The file of an encoding I wrote in Python. I want to add this file to the task scheduler and run it automatically every day, but when I open the .BAT file, the command window comes up immediately after the file is opened and closes suddenly. I tested this code in Python and saw it works.

And, when I double-click the file with the extension .PY and open it, the command window opens and the codes work. .PY extension does not work with task scheduler. How can I fix this, I would be glad if you could help.

```
import tweepy
import time


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('*','*')
auth.set_access_token('*','*')


api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
user = api.me()

search = 'books'
nrTweets = 500

import time

time_limit_sec = 10 * 60
start_time = time.time()

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(nrTweets):
    if (time.time()-start_time) > time_limit_sec:
        break

    try: 
        print('Tweet Liked')
        tweet.favorite()

        time.sleep(10)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: If the batch file contains only one command line which is running Python executable with the file name of the Python script file to run, there is no need to use a batch file at all interpreted by Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. Just configure in properties of scheduled task to run `python.exe` with full qualified file name and specify as arguments the full qualified file name of the Python script file and define also the __Start in__ directory path of the directory which should be the current directory on starting `python.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you double click a .py file it runs the code in an interpreter. If you want to run a script in the terminal all you have to do is call python and pass in the path to the script as the second argument.

The following solution will depend on where you have Python.exe installed. In the .bat file add the following lines:

If you have python.exe in your path you can do

```
python "C:\Users\Desktop\path_to\python_file.py"
```

If you want to explicit of where you have python.exe installed:

```
"C:\Users\Programs\path_to_python_installation\python.exe" "C:\Users\Desktop\path_to\python_file.py"
```